# How To Store Messages on ActiveMQ Artemis Multicast Queue Even When There are No Subscribers

Tags: message-queue, spring-jms, activemq-artemis

## PRECURSOR

I am still new to message queues so for practice I am creating a chat app that supports private chats and group chats. I have done the private chats well, but I am having an issue with the group chats, particularly with ActiveMQ's multicast semantics.

I am using JMS to create the queue like this:

```java
public boolean sendGroupMessage(String toGroupId, GroupMessageDTO message) {
    try {
        String jsonObj = new ObjectMapper().writer().withDefaultPrettyPrinter().writeValueAsString(message);
        jmsTemplate.send("group-" + toGroupId, messageCreator -> {
            TextMessage deliverable = messageCreator.createTextMessage();
            deliverable.setText(jsonObj);
            return deliverable;
        });
        
        convenienceMethods.addGroupMessageToStore(message);
        return Boolean.TRUE;
    }
    catch (Exception ex) {
        log.error("Service encountered error trying to send group message: {}", ex.getMessage());
        return Boolean.FALSE;
    }
}
```

So if I supply the `toGroupId` variable as `1234`, Artemis creates a multicast address with the name `group-1234` which is what I expect

## PROBLEM

Although the correct address is being created, and is being set to multicast (i.e. pub/sub semantics) as I expect, the message is not being added to any queue when I have no subscribers on the address. I am using a STOMP client logic to subscribe to the address and when I have one or two or more clients subscribed to the address, the messages do reach each client as they should in a group chat.

## EXPECTATION

1. What I want is to be able to send messages to the multicast address even when there is no subscribers (imagine these messages are coming from the insides of the app and not from a group member e.g to announce new app features), and when one subscriber attaches to the address, they should receive the message. Even so, the message should not be purged until all people in the group (multicast queue) have received it.
2. I want the address to be able to remember who are all the people that should be subscribed to it so that it can correctly perform the task in expectation 1 above. Remember that there is no JMS listener config in my app because the listeners are all JMS clients.

So how can I achieve this?

PS. If it helps, here is what I think is the relevant part of my JMS config:

```java
@Bean
public JmsTemplate jmsTemplate() {
    JmsTemplate template = new JmsTemplate();
    template.setConnectionFactory(connectionFactory());
    template.setMessageConverter(messageConverter());
    template.setPubSubDomain(true);
    template.setDestinationResolver(destinationResolver());
    template.setDeliveryPersistent(true);
    return template;
}

@Bean
DynamicDestinationResolver destinationResolver() {
    return new DynamicDestinationResolver() {
        @Override
        public Destination resolveDestinationName(Session session, String destinationName, boolean pubSubDomain) throws JMSException {
            if(destinationName.startsWith("group-")) {
                pubSubDomain = true;
            }
            else {
                pubSubDomain = false;
            }
            return super.resolveDestinationName(session,destinationName,pubSubDomain);
        }
    };
}
```

Comment: You say that when you send a message using Spring JMS to a topic that a multicast queue is created on the broker. This is actually _not_ the expected behavior. The expected behavior is that when a message is sent to a JMS topic then an _address_ is created on the broker, not a queue. Can you confirm that simply sending a message to a JMS topic that doesn't exist on the broker already results in the creation of a multicast queue as originally stated?

Comment: You say that messages are not being added to the multicast queue when there are no subscribers. This is _not_ the expected behavior. Any multicast queue on an address should receive any message sent to that address no matter if the queue has consumers or not. The nuance here is that pub/sub subscribers are represented with a queue on the corresponding address so that, generally speaking, if there are no subscribers then there are no queues on the address and therefore messages sent to the address are discarded. Can you confirm that you have queues on the address when you have no subscribers?

Comment: You say that you're using a STOMP client to subscribe to a _queue_. However, unless you're using the fully-qualified-queue-name with your STOMP client (which is rare) then your STOMP client should be subscribing to an _address_, not a queue. In your example the STOMP client would subscribe to the address named `group-1234`. Once subscribed there would be a multicast queue created on this address representing that subscription. Any message sent to that address would then be routed to that queue and delivered to the subscriber. Can you confirm you're subscribing to a queue, not an address?

Comment: You say you want to send messages to a multicast queue. However, unless you're using the fully-qualified-queue-name (which is rare) you will be sending messages to an _address_, not a queue. Generally speaking, any message sent to an address will be delivered to all the multicast queues on that address. This is how you can get pub/sub semantics. Please confirm you want to send messages to a multicast queue rather than an address as expected.

Comment: Generally speaking, it may be helpful to read through the [address model documentation](https://activemq.apache.org/components/artemis/documentation/latest/address-model.html) to understand how addresses, queues, and routing types fit together.

Comment: @JustinBertram sorry for the confusing terms. By MULTICAST QUEUE, I mean Multicast Address. And yes, when a STOMP client sends a SUBSCRIBE frame to **group-1234**, a queue is created under that address with some information about the client that subscribed. So the problem is when the client falls off and some messages are sent to that address by the server, the message never reaches the address, and when the client comes back online, they won't ever know a message actually was sent.

Answer (score 0):

What you're currently seeing is the expected behavior as it conforms with traditional pub/sub semantics. However, there are a few ways to change the behavior.

First, you can use a "[retroactive address](https://activemq.apache.org/components/artemis/documentation/latest/retroactive-addresses.html)":

> A "retroactive" address is an address that will preserve messages sent to it for queues which will be created on it in the future. This can be useful in, for example, publish-subscribe use cases where clients want to receive the messages sent to the address before they actually connected and created their multicast "subscription" queue. Typically messages sent to an address before a queue was created on it would simply be unavailable to those queues, but with a retroactive address a fixed number of messages can be preserved by the broker and automatically copied into queues subsequently created on the address. This works for both anycast and multicast queues.

Second, you can use a [*durable* subscription](https://activemq.apache.org/components/artemis/documentation/latest/stomp.html#durable-subscriptions) from your STOMP client instead of the default non-durable subscription. This will mitigate the problem that messages are lost if the subscriber disconnects after subscribing initially. However, keep in mind that it's important for the subscribe to explicitly delete the durable subscription when it is finished otherwise the subscription queue will be orphaned and will just sit there accumulating messages and consuming broker resources. To be clear, the broker can be configured to automatically delete orphaned subscription queues, but that risks deleting messages for a consumer that will return in the future to retrieve them.